# Python - CSV reader - unable to read all lines

Tags: python, csv, reader

I have the following snippet

```
import csv

data = {}
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, quotechar=None)
    count = 0
    for row in spamreader:
        data.update({row[0]:row[1]})
        count+=1
        

print(count)
print(len(data))
```

The file `data.csv` contains a total of 234611 rows and 2 columns.

The output is:

> 234611
>
> 52183

Now the reader is able to read all lines but unable to populate them into the `data` dictionary. Any idea how to debug this issue?
Also, it's worth mentioning that the csv file contains a lot of non-english characters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dictionary discards (or rather rewrites) values for duplicate keys. Are you sure there are no duplicate entries in the csv file?

If you want to collect all values for a given key, use `defaultdict(list)`.

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, quotechar=None)
    count = 0
    for row in spamreader:
        data[row[0]].append(row[1])
        count+=1


print(count)
print(len(data))
```

Comment: Oh yes there are some duplicate entries. Totally forgot about that. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you are adding duplicate keys (`row[0]`) to the dictionary. You could ensure the keys are unique by using `count` or appending `count` to `row[0]` instead.